# Relativistic Particles

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

> The question:
>   An electron is moving at $0.6c$ in the lab frame. For an observer moving at $0.8c$ in the same direction as the electron's motion, what is the electron's kinetic energy (in MeV)?

My attempts at a solution:
I thought to use
$u' = (u - v) / (1 - uv/c^2) = -0.65c$

to obtain the speed of the electron in the moving observer's frame and from there calculate the kinetic energy. However, I don't think this right.

Comment: Why do you think that is not right?

Comment: The section this question is from is on 4 momentum and relativistic energy.